# HDFS and Spark: Best way to write a file and reuse it from another program

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I have some results from a Spark application saved in the HDFS as files called part-r-0000X (X= 0, 1, etc.). And, because I want to join the whole content in a file, I'm using the following command:

`hdfs dfs -getmerge srcDir destLocalFile`

The previous command is used in a bash script which makes empty the output directory (where the `part-r-...` files are saved) and, inside a loop, executes the above `getmerge` command.

The thing is I need to use the resultant file in another Spark program which need that merged file as input in the HDFS. So I'm saving it as local and then I upload it to the HDFS.

I've thought another option which is write the file from the Spark program in this way:

```
outputData.coalesce(1, false).saveAsTextFile(outPathHDFS)
```

But I've read coalesce() doesn't help with the performance.

Any other ideas? suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Why would the 2nd Spark program require a _single_ file? That's nonsense for a distributed computing framework.

Comment: First let's talk about coalesce. coalesce can help if you want to reduce your data partitions without shuffle but it's to use with caution. coalesce(1) is actually an anti-pattern to use just in case your data fits on the master node i.e after some aggregations that yield a relatively small DataFrame. coalesce(1) will pull all the data from your nodes into the driver (master) which can overwhelm the driver and might cause and OOME.

Comment: Secondly, I agree with @SamsonScharfrichter if your job require a single file (one partition) you don't need spark.

Comment: If you want one output file, you probably want repartition(1) instead of coalesce(1).  As asked above, why can't your 2nd Spark program read in multiple files into an RDD or a dataframe?

Comment: You're right! Your comments have made me thinking about this and I'm using the par-r-000XX files from a program as input to the other. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution that I've found so far was:

```
outputData.saveAsTextFile(outPath, classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec])
```

Which saves the `outputData` in compressed `part-0000X.gz` files under the `outPath` directory.

And, from the other Spark app, it reads those files using this:

```
val inputData = sc.textFile(inDir + "part-00*", numPartition)
```

Where `inDir` corresponds to the `outPath`.

Answer (score 2):

You wish to merge all the files into a single one so that you can load all the files at once into a Spark rdd, is my guess.

Let the files be in Parts(0,1,....) in HDFS.

Why not load it with wholetextFiles, which actually does what you need.

```
wholeTextFiles(path, minPartitions=None, use_unicode=True)[source]
```

Read a directory of text files from HDFS, a local file system (available on all nodes), or any Hadoop-supported file system URI. Each file is read as a single record and returned in a key-value pair, where the key is the path of each file, the value is the content of each file.

If use_unicode is False, the strings will be kept as str (encoding as utf-8), which is faster and smaller than unicode. (Added in Spark 1.2)

For example, if you have the following files:

hdfs://a-hdfs-path/part-00000 hdfs://a-hdfs-path/part-00001 ... hdfs://a-hdfs-path/part-nnnnn

Do `rdd = sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(“hdfs://a-hdfs-path”)`, then rdd contains:

(a-hdfs-path/part-00000, its content) (a-hdfs-path/part-00001, its content) ... (a-hdfs-path/part-nnnnn, its content)

Comment: I've read this is suitable only for small files. Anyway, I've modified my code to use the output (part-r-000xx files) as input to the other program. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try SPARK BucketBy.

This is a nice feature via df.write.saveAsTable(), but this format can only be read by SPARK. Data shows up in Hive metastore but cannot be read by Hive, IMPALA.